# InitializeComponent Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, service

I am working on writing a basic service.  I'm adding a hidden form so I can catch Logon and LogOff events, etc.

I've tried following the example from Microsoft at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.aspx

I don't know why but I get the error: 'The name InitializeComponent does not exist in the current context.  This happens for my hidden form object:

```
public partial class HiddenForm : Form
{
    public HiddenForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Whether I re-type the code or cut and paste from Microsoft, I still get the same error.  What is causing this?

Comment: If the code doesn't have an accompanying designer file, then the error is accurate.

Comment: So the next really dumb question is how do I create a designer file?

Comment: I'm assuming you created a blank code page and pasted code.  If you want a Form, use the designer.  New->Windows Form.  You should get something like Form1.cs with two subordinate files:  Form1.designer.cs and Form1.resx.

Comment: Wow.  Thanks!  I didn't think I actually had to have a Windows Form in the project.